# script to remove string and keep numbers from files

Tags: bash, sed, awk

The titles of my files are formatted like the following:

- fileName01
- file07
- fileTitle8
- fileName20
- There is no delimiter between the string and numbers and the String character is not equal on each line.
- I want to output just the numbers from the end of the filename:
- 01
- 07
- 8
- 20

Comment: - If the pattern filename123.mp3 , and the O/p must be 123.mp3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you specifically want *only* the numbers and there is a possibility of non-alphanumeric characters, you can use `sed` and `[^0-9]`:

```
cat filename | sed 's|[^0-9]||g'
```

Additionally, if the possibility of duplicates exists and order is not an issue, you can combine this with `sort` and `uniq`:

```
cat filename | sed 's|[^0-9]||g' | sort | uniq
```

This last example will give you a distinct list of numbers found in the file; however, it does respect a leading `0` (i.e. - `8` != `08`).

**UPDATE** (bash-only):

```
while read line; do \
    echo ${line//[^0-9]/}; \
done < filename
```

Though less readable (from my point of view), it is a viable alternative that accomplishes the same goal. Also, appending `|sort | uniq` will still work with this example too.

**EDIT** (file-extensions)
To keep file-extensions (or any text *after* the first instance of numbers), per a comment by the OP, removing the `g` from the `sed` command and adding a `*` will handle this:

```
cat filename | sed 's|[^0-9]*||'
```

This will keep everything after the *first* instance of numbers, so `filename123.mp3` becomes `123.mp3`, and `file123part456.txt` becomes `123part456.txt`.

If you need an extremely sensitive match to specifically get **only** the last numbers and any existing file-extension (with the possibility of no file-extension, as the original question shows examples of), you can use `grep` with the `-P` and `-o` flags:

```
grep -Po "[0-9]*(\..*)?" filename
```

This will cause `filename123.mp3` to return `123.mp3`, and `file123part456.txt` to return `456.txt`. The `-P` flag indicates to interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression; the `-o` indicates to return only the matching part of the lines - not the full line that matches.

Comment: - If the pattern filename123.mp3 , The O/p can be 123.mp3

Comment: @KhaledLela: So you only want to remove the string before the number?

Comment: @KhaledLela Updated to support file-extensions; if this was a possibility from the beginning, you really should have mentioned it in your original post - especially in the examples (it changes the code a lot!)

Answer (score 6):

Use tr:

```
cat filename | tr -d [:alpha:]
```

Comment: Ohh... keep forgetting about that new fancy `:alpha:`.  I learned `bash` on Ultrix 3.2 back in the 1980's.

Comment: There is always a shorter code :)  `tr -d [:alpha:] < filename`

Comment: @fork0 +1 Yes, avoid the Useless Use of `cat` -- http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @fork0 that's better, saves one process!

Comment: What happens if the strings contain other characters then `[:alpha:]`? I think the complement to `[:digit:]` and newline would be more reliable: `tr -cd '[:digit:]\n' < filename`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `grep -o` for the question posted by the OP:

```
grep -o '[0-9]*' filenames
```

#### Edit

In the comments the OP asked how to remove leading text, in that case use:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ASCII strings

echo "HelloTrailz23" | tr -d '[A-Z][a-z]'

If you are dealing with unicode file names, all bets are off.

Comment: Numbers are numbers even in Unicode. If you want to get fancy, use the Unicode number property, and a tool which allows you to access it, such as Perl.

Comment: @tripleee -- That is true, but doesn't change the fact that my regex wouldn't remove unicode characters or punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo filename123onetwothree.999 | sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)$/\1/'
999
```

This extracts only the numbers from the *end* of the filename.

To make it universal use:

```
sed 's/.*[^[:digit:]]\([[:digit:]]*\)$/\1/' file
```

Comment: - The pattern filename123.mp3 , The O/p must be 123.mp3

Comment: Hardly consistent with your original problem statement!

Answer (score 0):

I always like to use bash's variable string manipulation. It's overkill, but it quickly works on the command line.

```
for i in fileName01 file07 fileTitle8 fileName20 file123._mp3 ; do echo ${i//[!0-9]} ; done
```

Result:

```
01
07
8
20
1233
```

The //[!0-9] within the ${i} variable removes everything except numbers that are in each string as it loops through the list.